# achartengine X and Y plots overlapping for each other for stacked bar graph?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am Using achartEngine to plot stacked bar-graph.My plot for X an Y Values are overlapping and plot with Lesser value than the other is squeezed out.Below is my builddataset and chartfactory

```
protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(v[k]);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(i,series.toXYSeries());
        }
        return dataset;
    }
```

my chartfactory:

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(NTViewGraph.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
                Type.STACKED);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per given link:

```
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-For-Enterprise/Enterprise-Grade-Charts-part-II/ba-p/23420

Use below methods and pass 0 to that methods.
If you set it to 0 then it will not show any label and shows label that is externally set by You. And if you pass 1 then it shows 1 label in the interval of 10.

renderer.setXLabels(0);     
renderer.setYLabels(0);
```

I hope this will help you.